# Regex for a Complex Password

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I've got this Regex as a data annotation on a password field in a C# .NET MVC project.

```
[RegularExpression("(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[*+\\/|!\"£$%^&*()#[\\]@~'?><,.=-_]).{6,}", ErrorMessage = "Password must be between 6 and 20 characters and contain one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter, one digit and one special character.")]
```

I want to make the following passwords invalid:-

- Testing
- Testing1
- TesTinG123

The following would be valid:-

- Testing1*
- T&sting123*
- %F&y5HD$S

I would like a minimum of 6 characters, with at least one uppercase, one lower case, one digit and one special character. I hope the above regex would do it, but it lets **Testing12** and **Tester12** through as valid passwords.

What can I change in the above to get what I am expecting? I assumed the above requires one uppercase, one lowercase, one numeric and one special character but obviously I am wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Personally I wouldn't jam all those requirements into one regular expression.  You can do the length check with `string.Length` and then you could use 3 simple regular expressions for the minimum of one character of a certain type.  IMO that would be more readable and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to escape `]` properly (it is advised to even put it at the start of the character class so that in .NET it could be parsed as a literal `]` - for the client side validation, it needs to be escaped even there) and remember that a hyphen inside a character class creates a range (e.g. `[=-_]`), so it must be put at the end/start of the character class or at the end to denote a literal `-`).

Use

```
"^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\]*+\\/|!\"£$%^&*()#[@~'?><,.=_-]).{6,}$"
                                         ^^                             ^
```

Or, if you just want to require at least 1 char that is not alphanumeric, use

```
"^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\W_]).{6,}$"
```

where `[\W_]` matches any char but a word char (i.e. `[^\p{L}\p{N}_]` or - on client side - `[^a-zA-Z0-9_]`) + `_`.

The `^` and `$` anchors are redundant in the RegularExpressionAttribute pattern, but they won't do any harm.

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3d.*%5b0-9%5d%29%28%3f%3d.*%5ba-z%5d%29%28%3f%3d.*%5bA-Z%5d%29%28%3f%3d.*%5b%5c%5d*%2b%5c%5c%2f%7c!%5c%22%c2%a3%24%25%5e%26*%28%29%23%5b%40%7e%27%3f%3e%3c%2c.%3d_-%5d%29.%7b6%2c%7d%24&i=Testing%0d%0aTesting1%0d%0aTesTinG123%0d%0a%0d%0aTesting1*%0d%0aT%26sting123*%0d%0a%25F%26y5HD%24S&o=m).

Comment: Also found that the following seems to work very well:-

`"(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\\W]).{6,}"`

where \\W means any non-letter and non-number.

Comment: That is up to you, I do not know the requirements. The problem was with the prematurely closed character class. The `]` before `@` in `[*+\\/|!\"£$%^&*()#[\\]@~'?><,.=-_]` closed it, and the rest was parsed as a *sequence* of chars.